# Twitter Bootstrap - The best way to customize dropdowns

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

I'm new in bootstrap and i have a doubt.
I want to create two differents dropdowns in a same page, but with different designs (anyone like default bootstrap). What the most elegant way of doing this? Thanks for any help.

Comment: Just give them different classes, and override the base styles accordingly

Comment: Or define your classes so they are mixable `<div class="dropdown red-bg small-menu" /><div class="dropdown blue-bg big-menu" />`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just add a different class with it's own styles... Then add those directly to the classes on their respective `divs`.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/brbcoding/XdQjX/4/)**

**CSS**

```css
/* please don't name your classes like this */

.left-dd {
    background-color: blue;
    font-size: 2em;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 2em;
    color: white;
}

.right-dd {
    background-color: red;
    font-family: comic-sans;
    font-size: 0.5em;

}
```

**HTML**

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu right-dd" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
      <li>Some dropdown content</li>
      <li>Some dropdown content</li>
      <li>Some dropdown content</li>
      <li>Some dropdown content</li>
      <li>Some dropdown content</li>
  </ul>
```